# ResourcesNotFoundException while passing value to adapter constructor

Tags: android

I get the given exception with the following code. Though I pass the same resource id to the adapter, why do I get the given exception?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "mykey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:uk");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable  {


    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

}
```

}

Exception:

```
02-07 23:28:23.390: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28967): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-07 23:28:38.520: E/Trace(29242): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-07 23:28:38.530: D/ActivityThread(29242): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
02-07 23:28:38.530: D/ActivityThread(29242): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
02-07 23:28:38.530: D/ActivityThread(29242): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
02-07 23:28:38.700: D/libEGL(29242): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-07 23:28:38.700: D/libEGL(29242): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-07 23:28:38.700: D/libEGL(29242): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Merge)
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): Build Date: 07/09/13 Tue
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): Local Branch: AU_41
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): Remote Branch: 
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): Local Patches: 
02-07 23:28:38.710: I/Adreno200-EGL(29242): Reconstruct Branch: 
02-07 23:28:38.740: D/OpenGLRenderer(29242): Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 23:28:49.860: D/AndroidRuntime(29242): Shutting down VM
02-07 23:28:49.860: W/dalvikvm(29242): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d65378)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070000 type #0x12 is not valid
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2108)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1188)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1115)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1081)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:956)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:938)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-07 23:28:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(29242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: search the value 0x7f070000 in your R.java file. That may give you a better ide as to which resource is causing your trouble.

Comment: the second param should be a resource ie quoting from docs  "resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `/gen/R.java` file to find what element has the id `#0x7f070000`.

I think that the problem is here:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

you have an element `autoCompleteTextView1` inside your layout `activity_main.xml`
that element is really a type `AutoCompleteTextView` ?

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
```